# Use .yml variable into @Scheduled(cron = variable)

Tags: spring-boot, groovy, cron, yaml, scheduled-tasks

I got a groovy class

```
@Configuration
class SchedulerTest {

    SomeService service


    @Inject
    SchedulerTest (SomeService service) {
        this.service = service
    }


    @Scheduled(cron = '0/5 * * * * *')
    void doSomething() {
        service.someMethod()   
    }
}
```

and got a .yml file

```
scheduler:
    cron: 0/5 * * * * *
```

I want to use the .yml variable to the cron value into @Scheduled, like

`@Scheduled(cron = schdulers.cron)`

How can I make this work?

Obs. I`m very new in development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put

```
@Scheduled(cron = '${scheduler.cron}')
void doSomething() {
    service.someMethod()
}
```

With the parameter in single quotes

With double quotes, groovy is trying to evaluate the template

Comment: That's it. Thank you